# UI to show sleep functionality Graph

Tags: react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggiOi.png)

I want to show sleep functionality in graph format but unable to do UI.Any help will be appreciated. Please find attached image for reference.

have tried as below.

```
 <HorizontalBarChart
   style={{ height: 50 }}
   legend={{ enabled: false }}
   chartDescription={{ text: "" }}
   data={this.state.bardata}
   xAxis={this.state.xAxis} 
   yAxis={this.state.yAxis} 
   drawGridBackground={false}
   drawBorders={false}
   touchEnabled={true} 
   dragEnabled={false}
   scaleEnabled={false}
   scaleXEnabled={false} 
   scaleYEnabled={false} 
   pinchZoom={false} 
   doubleTapToZoomEnabled={false} 
   dragDecelerationEnabled={true}
   dragDecelerationFrictionCoef={0.99}
   keepPositionOnRotation={false} 
   contentInset={{ top: 10, bottom: 10 }}
  />
```

Comment: Any piece of relevant code?

Comment: @HagaiHarari I don't have exact code yet, but I have tried as below. <HorizontalBarChart style={{ height: 50 }} legend={{ enabled: false }} chartDescription={{ text: "" }} data={this.state.bardata} xAxis={this.state.xAxis}  yAxis={this.state.yAxis} drawGridBackground={false} drawBorders={false} touchEnabled={true} dragEnabled={false} scaleEnabled={false} scaleXEnabled={false} scaleYEnabled={false} pinchZoom={false} doubleTapToZoomEnabled={false} dragDecelerationEnabled={true} dragDecelerationFrictionCoef={0.99} keepPositionOnRotation={false} contentInset={{ top: 10, bottom: 10 }} /></View>